# CSS html * except some class?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply this to everything except a specific class and its children

```
html * {

 box-shadow: none !important;
 border: none !important;
 color: white;

     }
```

I tried this but not working

```
html *:not(.myclass *) {

 box-shadow: none !important;
 border: none !important;
 color: white;

     }
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well?

Answer (score 8):

Not a direct answer to what you are asking, but is it not better to potentially have this:

```
html * {    
 box-shadow: none;
 border: none;
 color: white;
}
```

And then override it specifically in those classes where it is wanted, e.g.

```
.myclass {
    color:blue;
}
```

This is more how you might expect to find it.  Note that I removed the 'important' declarations from the first * specifier as this makes things more difficult to potentially override in the future.

Comment: haha i know how to do this , i just want to know if there is a faster way lol

Comment: @Slown1970 - Appreciate that it may just be faster now to update the overall declaration, but it will probably slow you down in the months to come.

Answer (score 1):

just add the `:not(.myclass)` selector between the `body` and the `*` and the selector :not again after the `*:not(.myclass)`

```css
body :not(.myclass) *:not(.myclass) {
       box-shadow: none !important;
       border: none !important;
       color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>test 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="myclass">
  <h1 class="myclass">test 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="myclass">
  <h1>test 3</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 class="myclass">test 4</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this will fail if you add an extra wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/go2sf3vx/ .. and the use of `*` is not needed